# Putting variable value into another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out the below problem

```
var result = {"name":"Launches","Data":"50,56,34,25,25,55"}
```

how can we print this variables value(result) into below variable  using jquery or javascript

```
Series :[result];
```

any idea. I tried this by `document.write()` but it is writing into screen. But I need the above variables  value as input for Series .

I need a result like this

```
Series:[{"name":"Launches","Data":"50,56,34,25,25,55"}];
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'values' and 'results'?

Comment: sorry guys, not explaining properly. I just to print a value like this,
var result = {"name":"Launches","Data":"50,56,34,25,25,55"}
Series :[result];
then the output should be like


Series:[{"name":"Launches","Data":"50,56,34,25,25,55"}];

Comment: In that case simply do document.write( "[" + JSON.stringify(result) + "]" )

Comment: If you are looking to convert the data to an array you can do ... var series = result.Data.split(",");

Comment: are you trying to wrap your Object in an Array?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by value?

`result` is an object which has 2 key-value pairs.

You can say `result.Data` to return "50,56,34,25,25,55",

or `result.name` to return "Launches"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.write(result.Data);
document.write(result.name);

var Series = result.Data;
```